# trying to have a group be able to read/write to a directory

Tags: permissions

First I'm a NEWBIE - I'm using a Bitnami stack to deploy a Rails app.

Bitnami has the rails applications in `/opt/bitnami/projects`.

I created a group called `deployers`. My login is `bitnami`. So, I added `bitnami` to `deployers` (I'm the only developer right now).

So,

- `whoami` = `bitnami`
- `groups bitnami` = `bitnami : bitnami adm dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev admin deployers`

Then I ran these commands:

```
sudo chown -R root:deployers projects
sudo chmod -R 0766 projects
```

I thought those commands would give `bitnami` in group `deployers` the read/write access I need.

But, now I can't even `cd projects`. I get `bash: cd: projects: Permission denied`.

The permissions on the projects directory look like this:

```
projects Directory drwxrw-rw- root deployers
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `cd projects` because you must have execute permission on a directoryto do so. Run this to set the permissions:

```
sudo find projects -type f -exec chmod -R 664 {} \;
sudo find projects -type d -exec chmod -R 775 {} \;
```

The first applies read and write permissions to files and the second applies read, write and execute permission to directories.

Answer (score 0):

The `execution` permission for directory means that you can `cd` into it. So if you want to `cd` into directory `projects` on groups behalf you have to set the `execute` bit on that directory:

```
chmod g+x projects
```